# Cross tab report in Crystal Report

Tags: crosstab, crystal-reports-2010

I am quite new to cross tab type reports in crystal report and I want to show multiple users multiple details.
So that I have columns as username and row containing details of the same.

Like:

```
          User1     User2    User3    User4    User5
Details1:  aaa       bbb      ccc     dddd     eeee

Details2:  123       345      534     566      87667

Details3:  geg      dhrth   htrhytr   ghdf     ytryr
```

But I am unable to get the interface as total, subtotal summary etc fields are quite confusing.
Also I am not interested in grouping my rows on the basis of one field and then showing details in it.

Answer (score 1):

Create a cross tab report and in Row area you put Your details and in column are you put your user, and don't forgot to put the Summarized fields. It works fine. No need to do any coding all the things should manage from your stored procedure.

Comment: I had tried that earlier but the look of the report is quite vague as it is mandatory to have a group and it is not helping me.